# Using tasks.json in Visual Studio Code to transpile both typescript and sass

Tags: css, sass, typescript, visual-studio-code, transpiler

I want to transpile both typescript and sass to javascript and css respectively. At The moment running this tasks.json file transpiles my typescript to javascript:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",

    // The command is tsc. Assumes that tsc has been installed using npm install -g typescript
    "command": "tsc",

    // The command is a shell script
    "isShellCommand": true,

    // Show the output window only if unrecognized errors occur.
    "showOutput": "silent",

    // args is the HelloWorld program to compile.
    "args": ["public/app/boot.ts"],

    // use the standard tsc problem matcher to find compile problems
    // in the output.
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

I only need to specify boot.ts and it transpiles all .ts files to js. It might be because my boot.ts file imports all my ts files. Here is my boot.ts file:

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {HelloWorld} from './hello_world'
import {TodoApp} from './todo_app'
bootstrap(HelloWorld);
bootstrap(TodoApp);
```

I would like to add code into the tasks.json file that will transpile the sass to css.

Here is a code snippet of what I could do to only transpile my sass:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "node-sass",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["styles.scss", "styles.css"]
}
```

How do I add that code snippet so that it transpiles both the sass and the typescript?

Also, Will I be wanting to add any new sass files to the args array in tasks.json as I create them?

Comment: Not sure you can achieve this directly from tasks.json (not sure you can't though). I would go for an external task runner such as [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), build my tasks there, then run those tasks either from command line or Code (which supports both). This would also make your project more usable in other editors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't do this with the `tsc` command. use `npm` instead.

### package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc public/app/boot.ts && node-sass styles.scss styles.css"
  }
}
```

### tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "args": ["-s", "run"],
    "tasks": [{
      "taskName": "build",
      "problemMatcher": "$tsc",
      "isBuildCommand": true
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure when this feature was added, so it may not of helped the OP. I like this because it's built-in to the IDE. For the OP case they just need to decide which should be completed before the other.

The following snippet allows multiple tasks to be run, one after the other. A pre-build, build, and post-build, when building your project select the "**Pre-Build & Build & Post-Build**" to run them all. This is still a rather simple chain of tasks, and you could create multiple chains of any length with this technique, but they do tend to clutter up the tasks.json file.

```js
"tasks": [
  { 
    "label": "base",
    "detail": "Pre-Build",
    "type": "shell",
    "command":["echo"],
    "args": ["prebuild task"],
  },
  { 
    "label": "build",
    "detail": "Pre-Build & Build",
    "type": "shell",
    "command":["echo"],
    "args": ["build task"],
    "dependsOn":["base"],
  },
  { 
    "label": "Post Build",
    "detail": "Pre-Build & Build & Post-Build",
    "type": "shell",
    "command":["echo"],
    "args": ["Post build task"],
    "dependsOn":["build"],
  }
]
```