# Visual studio code build and watch both typescript as sass

Tags: typescript, sass, visual-studio-code, transpiler

I am setting up an `Angular2` project in `Visual studio code` with `Sass` files for styling. But I cannot seem to get sass to compile in the correct way.

*I am trying to compile (**on save!**) all .ts files and .scss in my src directory. The .scss files and .ts are placed in subdirectories of the src (my main) directory. I include all my _.scss files into one .scss file and I want to compile that to one css file. I also want to compile all my .ts files into one .js file (not minified)*

**Typescript compiler**

For typescript I am using the default `$tsc` compiler of visual studio code

**Sass compiler**

For Sass files (.scss) I am using `node-sass V4.5.1`

---

**Setup**

I have the following setup in my tasks.json:

```
{
   "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "npm",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "showOutput": "always",
    "args": ["-s", "run"],
    "tasks": [{
      "taskName": "buildAndWatch",
      "problemMatcher": "$tsc",
      "isBuildCommand": true
    }]
}
```

I have the following code in my package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "buildAndWatch": "tsc && node-sass --watch"
  }
```

my tsconfig.json:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "build/",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
     "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "watch": true
  }, 
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build"
  ]
}
```

---

**Questions**

- Can the problemMatcher '$tsc' handle node-sass errors or should I use an other problemMatcher (if so, how could I do this?)
- Is it even possible to compile and watch both my .ts and .scss files with one task?

*An example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688736/using-tasks-json-in-visual-studio-code-to-transpile-both-typescript-and-sass), but that one doesn't watch and recompiles the files*

---

**Almost got it Today** I found out how to watch and build my sass and my typescript. For this I am using the following npm scripts:

```
 "scripts": {
    "Start:Development":"npm run Build:Typescript && npm run Watch:Sass",
    "Build:Typescript": "tsc",
    "Build:Sass": "node-sass ./src/assets/scss/main.scss ./src/assets/css/stylesheet.css",
    "Watch:Sass": "npm run Build:Sass && npm run Build:Sass -- -w"
  }
```

I call `Start:Development` and npm does the rest. But, I still have a problem. vs code won't run both watches. I can run the `Build:Typescript` and `Watch:Sass` separate from each other, but not at the same time. If I try that then only my typescript will be compiled. Anyone can help me with this?